# Добавление текста при нажатии jquery

Tags: javascript

Есть поле для ввода, кнопка и поле для вывода. В поле для вывода уже заполнено value. Нужно, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку текст не перезаписывался, а добавлялся к уже существующему.
Вот пример

```
<div>
<input type ="text" id="first">
</div>
<div>
<input type ="button" value="button" id="btn">
</div>
<div>
<input type ="text" value="someText" id="last">
</div>

$("#btn").on('click', function () {
    var t1 = $('#first').val();
    $('#last').val(t1);
});
```

Вот на стороннем ресурсе
https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/7609/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Так:

```js
$("#btn").on('click', function () {
    var t1 = $('#first').val();
    console.log(t1);
    $('#last').val(function(i, val){
     return val + ' ' + t1;
    });
});
```

```css
p {
    margin: 1em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  
<div>
<input type ="text" id="first">
</div>
<div>
<input type ="button" value="button" id="btn">
</div>
<div>
<input type ="text" value="someText" id="last">
</div>
```

> [`.val( function(index, value) )`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-function)
>
> Атрибуту value будет присвоено значение, которое вернет функция
>   function. Функция для каждого из выбранных элементов. При вызове, ей
>   передаются следующие параметры: index (позиция элемента в наборе) и
>   value (текущее значение атрибута value у элемента).

Answer (score 7):

> ```
> $('#last').val(t1);
> ```

```
$('#last').val($('#last').val() + t1);
```

А лучше так:

```
var $last = $('#last');
$last.val($last.val() + t1);
```

Answer (score 2):

html

```js
$("#btn").on('click', function () {
    var t1 = $('#first').val();
    $('#last').val($('#last').val() + t1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<input type ="text" id="first">
</div>
<div>
<input type ="button" value="button" id="btn">
</div>
<div>
<input type ="text" value="someText" id="last">
</div>
```

Comment: этот ответ чем-то отличается от уже данных?

Comment: @Grundy, наличием сниппета, который мне было лень делать :)